# How to update Nested object in react state?

Tags: reactjs, state

This is the current state

```
state={
    product:[
        {id:1, title: 'demo product 1 ', price: 10, incart: 2},
        {id:2, title: 'demo product 2', price: 11, incart: 3},
    
    
    ],
}
```

I have a +1 button that increase the total number of product in incart.

```
// the onClick handler 
// prod arguments return a product object like this {id:1, title: 'demo product 1 ', price: 10, incart: 2}

handelIncrement= (prod) => {
    
    const newState = {...this.state.product, prod}  
    this.setState({ product: newState })  // giving an error
    
  }
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing is you pass an object to a product state and a product state is an array.

```js
handelIncrement= (prod) => {
    
    const newState = [...this.state.product, prod]  
    this.setState({ product: newState })  // giving an error
    
  }
```

Comment: I see, 
how can I overwrite the child object of the array?
my approach  [...this.state.product, prod] adding a new object into the array. 
but I want to overwrite the previous object that has the same id as prod.id

Comment: Then the best approach is using then index to update the data

Comment: Would you please show me the code?  I am not an expert.

Comment: Sure I will upload the code and you need to pass the current object index to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleIncrement= (prod) => {
    
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.product.map(el => (el.id === id ? {...el, text} : el))
    });
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To handleincrement() method you need to pass index to method to that.

```js
handelIncrement= (index,prod) => {
    //first copy data
    const copyProducts = [...product];
    //copy current object data
    const singleObjectData = { ...copyProducts[index] };
    //change object data
    singleObjectData = {//your new current prod};
    //put back to the same index
    copyProducts[index] = singleObjectData;
    //and update set
     this.setState({ product: copyProducts })
  }
```